# JavaFX using setCellValueFactory with org.neo4j.graphdb.Label name

Tags: javafx

I want to populate a TableView with the name of the Neo4j label name.
http://neo4j.com/api_docs/2.0.0/org/neo4j/graphdb/Label.html
Unfortunately the name is not accessible as a property but as a method.
In which way do I have to modify the PropertyValueFactor to call the name method?

What I got so far:

```
public ObservableList<Label> getLabels(long pNodeId){
    NodeLabelsDA nl = new NodeLabelsDA();
    return FXCollections.observableArrayList(nl.getLabels(pNodeId));
}

public void handleSelectedNode(long pNodeId){
    System.out.println("Node select: " + pNodeId);
    tblLabels.setItems(getLabels(pNodeId));
    tcLabelName.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Label, String>("name"));

}
```

What I need:

```
public void handleSelectedNode(long pNodeId){
    System.out.println("Node select: " + pNodeId);
    tblLabels.setItems(getLabels(pNodeId));
    tcLabelName.setCellValueFactory(
            ???? new MethodValueFactory<Label, String>(Label x -> x.name)); ???

}
```

Thanks a lot and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide a `Callback` implementation:

```
tcLabelName.setCellValueFactory((CellDataFeatures<Label, String> cellData) -> 
    new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().name()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help James_D unfortunately I receive the following error:
Lambda expression's parameter cellData is expected to be of type Object

Comment: What's your declaration of `tcLabelName`? I was assuming `TableColumn<Label, String> tcLabelName`.  And also check your imports: you should have `import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;`.

Comment: sorry my bad, missed the generic types in the declaration, works like a charm.
TableColumn<Label, String> 
Thanks a gain